# SqlBulkCopy for two tables with one-to-many association

Tags: c#, sql-server, one-to-many, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I have used `SqlBulkCopy` in my previous program and have enjoyed the speed-of-light advantage of its `INSERTS`. But then, I was only inserting things in one table only.

I now have two tables with a one-to-many association i.e. table `A` has a foreign key in table `B`. So each record in `B` carries an *id* that is the result of an insert in `A`.

I am wondering if there is a solution for this?

**Example:**

I will give a better example on this and hope we find a good solution eventually.

We have a table called *Contacts*. And since each contact can have zero or more Email addresses we will store those emails in a separate table called *ContactEmails*. So `Contacts.Id` will become *FK* on *ContactEmails* (say `ContactEmails.ContactId`).

Let's say we would like to insert 1000 *Contacts* and each will have zero or more *Emails*. And we of course want to use `SqlBulkCopy` *for both tables*.

The problem is, it is only when we insert a new Contact that we know his/her `Id`. Once the Contact is inserted, we know the inserted `Id` is e.g. 15. So we insert 3 emails for this contact and all three will have `ContactEmails.ContactId` value of 15. But we have no knowledge of 15 before the contact is inserted into the database.

We can insert all contacts as bulk into the table. But when it comes to their email, the connection is lost because emails do not know their own contacts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does SqlBulkCopy circumnavigate foreign key constraints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092091/how-does-sqlbulkcopy-circumnavigate-foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: @CyrilDurand the question does not work for me. My problem is that every row in `A` can have one or more child rows in `B`. But before we run the INSERT for `A` we do not know what the row id will be so that `B` will get the same. The row in `B` will only know its parent's id when its parent has been inserted. Isn't it right? So we can do a bulk insert for records in `A` but when it comes to be, they don't know their parents.

Comment: @CyrilDurand I updated the question with more information just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the constraints (foreign key) before bulk insert. Then enable it again.

Make sure you do not have referential integrity violations.

You can disable FK and CHECK constraints using below query:

```
ALTER TABLE foo NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE foo NOCHECK CONSTRAINT CK_foo_column
```

Primary keys and unique constraints can not be disabled, but this should be OK if I've understood you correctly.

Comment: The problem is, unless we insert a record in `A`, we do not know its id. So if there is a record in `B` it will not know it belongs to `A` unless its parent has already been created. So I don't think removing the constraints will solve the problem.

Comment: It is true, disabling constraints will not help in this case. Add more information in your question on how are you trying to do this. What have you tried so far and where is it you are getting an error or stuck. This will hep understand your problem.

Comment: OK I will try to add more info.

Comment: I tried to elaborate the problem a  bit further. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Me too have same question however not getting the solution, seems will have to end up doing bulk copy for parent first and then bulk copy for child table :(