# How do I capture the data passed in SqlBulkCopy using the Sql Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy, sql-server-profiler

I am using Sql Profiler all the time to capture the SQL statements and rerun problematic ones. Very useful.

However, some code uses the SqlBulkCopy API and I have no idea how to capture those. I see creation of temp tables, but nothing that populates them. Seems like SqlBulkCopy bypasses Sql Profiler or I do not capture the right events.

Comment: Are your tags correct? Is it a MySQL related question?

Comment: Of course, not. I did a mistake. Stupid me. This is Sql Server. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to capture the query to get the data or the inserting of the data?

Comment: @mark Ok, I was kinda guessing that based on the reference to seeing a temp table creation, but wanted to make sure since it was otherwise ambiguous. It would help if you can clarify that in the Question. Also, I do have partial good news and will post an answer soon.

Comment: @srutzky - looking forward.

Answer (score 16):

Capturing event info for bulk insert operations ( `BCP.EXE`, `SqlBulkCopy`, and I assume `BULK INSERT`, and `OPENROWSET(BULK...` ) is possible, but you won't be able to see the individual rows and columns.

Bulk Insert operations show up as a single (well, one per batch, and the default is to do all rows in a single batch) DML statement of:

```sql
INSERT BULK <destination_table_name> (
      <column1_name> <column1_datatype> [ COLLATE <column1_collation> ], ...
      ) [ WITH (<1 or more hints>) ]

<hints> := KEEP_NULLS, TABLOCK, ORDER(...), ROWS_PER_BATCH=, etc
```

You can find the full list of "hints" on the MSDN page for the [BCP Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx). Please note that SqlBulkCopy only supports a subset of those hints (e.g. `KEEP_NULLS`, `TABLOCK`, and a few others) but does *not* support `ORDER(...)` or `ROWS_PER_BATCH=` <sup>**</sup> (which is quite unfortunate, actually, as the `ORDER()` hint is needed in order to avoid a sort that happens in tempdb in order to allow the operation to be minimally logged (assuming the other conditions for such an operation have also been satisfied).

In order to see this statement, you need to capture any of the following events in SQL Server Profiler:

> SQL:BatchStarting
>   SQL:BatchCompleted
>   SQL:StmtStarting
>   SQL:StmtCompleted

You will also want to select, at least, the following columns (in SQL Server Profiler):

> TextData
>   CPU
>   Reads
>   Writes
>   Duration
>   SPID
>   StartTime
>   EndTime
>   RowCounts

And, since a user cannot submit an `INSERT BULK` statement directly, you can probably filter on that in Column Filters if you merely want to see these events and nothing else.

If you want to see the official notification that a `BULK INSERT` operation is beginning and/or ending, then you need to capture the following event:

> SQLTransaction

and then add the following Profiler columns:

> EventSubClass
>   ObjectName

For `ObjectName` you will always get events showing "BULK INSERT" and whether that is beginning or ending is determined by the value in `EventSubClass`, which is either "0 - Begin" or "1 - Commit" (and I suppose if it fails you should see "2 - Rollback").

If the `ORDER()` hint was not specified (and again, it *cannot* be specified when using `SqlBulkCopy`), then you will also get a "SQLTransaction" event showing "sort_init" in the `ObjectName` column. This event also has "0 - Begin" and "1 - Commit" events (as shown in the `EventSubClass` column).

Finally, even though you cannot see the specific rows, you can still see operations against the Transaction Log (e.g. insert row, modify IAM row, modify PFS row, etc) if you capture the following event:

> TransactionLog

and add the following Profiler column:

> ObjectID

The main info of interest will be in the `EventSubClass` column, but unfortunately it is just ID values and I could not find any translation of those values in MSDN documentation. However, I did find the following blog post by Jonathan Kehayias: [Using Extended Events in SQL Server Denali CTP1 to Map out the TransactionLog SQL Trace Event EventSubClass Values](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2011/01/03/using-extended-events-in-sql-server-denali-ctp1-to-map-out-the-transactionlog-sql-trace-event-eventsubclass-values.aspx).

@RBarryYoung pointed out that EventSubClass values and names can be found in the `sys.trace_subclass_values` catalog view, but querying that view shows that it has no rows for the `TransactionLog` event:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.trace_categories -- 12 = Transactions
SELECT * FROM sys.trace_events WHERE category_id = 12 -- 54 = TransactionLog
SELECT * FROM sys.trace_subclass_values WHERE trace_event_id = 54 -- nothing :(
```

---

<sup>**</sup> Please note that the `SqlBulkCopy.BatchSize` property is equivalent to setting the `-b` option for **BCP.EXE**, which is an operational setting that controls how each command will break up the rows into sets. This is not the same as the `ROWS_PER_BATCH=` hint which does not physically control how the rows are broken up into sets, but instead allows SQL Server to better plan how it will allocate pages, and hence reduces the number of entries in the Transaction Log (sometimes by quite a bit). Still my testing showed that:

- specifying `-b` for **BCP.EXE** did set the `ROWS_PER_BATCH=` hint to that same value.
- specifying the `SqlBulkCopy.BatchSize` property did *not* set the `ROWS_PER_BATCH=` hint, BUT, the benefit of reduced Transaction Log activity was somehow definitely there (magic?). The fact that the net effect is to still gain the benefit is why I did not mention it towards the top when I said that it was unfortunate that the `ORDER()` hint was not supported by `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: Isn't BatchSize, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize(v=vs.110).aspx , the equivalent of ROWS_PER_BATCH ?

Comment: @BruceDunwiddie No. The `SqlBulkCopy.BatchSize` property is equivalent to setting the `-b` option for BCP, although I just saw in the Profiler trace that BCP will use that value to set `ROWS_PER_BATCH=`. But setting `BatchSize` for SqlBulkCopy does _not_ set the `ROWS_PER_BATCH=` hint. But, setting that property _does_ still, somehow, allow for a performance boost. I will add this clarification to the answer.

Comment: IIRC, you can translate EventSubClass with the `sys.trace_subclass_values` catalog view.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I just checked and there are lots of values in that catalog view, but unfortunately, none of them are for the `TransactionLog` event. I will add that (and the query) to the answer.

Comment: @BruceDunwiddie I updated with more info. Section is at the bottom. Summary = they are not the same, but you still get the performance benefit, which is why I hadn't lamented it earlier ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You cann't capture `SqlBulkCopy` in SQL Profiler because `SqlBulkCopy` doesn't generate SQL at all when inserts data in SQL Server table. `SqlBulkCopy` works similar to `bcp` utility and loads data directly into SQL Server file system. It's even [can ignore FKs and triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092091/how-does-sqlbulkcopy-circumnavigate-foreign-key-constraints) when inserts the rows!

Comment: Regarding "`SqlBulkCopy` doesn't generate SQL at all when inserts data in SQL Server table.": that is absolutely not true. It does generate an INSERT statement, and that can be seen in SQL Server Profiler. It is an `insert bulk` operation. It is not possible to bypass SQL Server to inject data into the database. If that was possible, then it would invalidate ACID compliance. Your quote of the MSDN forum answer is out of context and misleading. The person was saying that the SELECT query cannot be distinguished from all other queries as being _definitely_ from BCP.

Comment: @srutzky thanks, I've removed that misleading quote. It's my fault, I forgot about the `insert bulk` statement. However this statement seems to be useless - it doesn't contain the data, only schema of destination table (am I wrong again?). Also, why you didn't post an answer instead of comment?

Comment: Hi there. I hadn't added an answer because I was waiting for clarification from the O.P. I have added one now :)